# Identity value for numpy ufunc reducers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which I want to find the maximum element of, so I call:

```
x = foo.max()
```

The problem is that `foo` is sometimes an empty array, and the `max` function (understandably) throws:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

This leads to my question:

Is there a way to supply the identity value for the reduction operation? (Ideally, one that will work for arbitrary numpy ufuncs with `reduce` methods.) Or am I stuck doing:

```
if foo.size > 0:
  x = foo.max()
else:
  x = 0  # or whatever identity value I choose
```

Comment: Isn't `trial ... except` the pythonic way to go about this?

Comment: In your code sample, I think you mean `if foo.size > 0:`.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the "pythonic" way to go about this is:

```
def safe_max(ar,default=np.nan):
    try:
        return np.max(ar)
    except ValueError:
        return default

x = safe_max(foo,0)
```

Considering that the maximum of an empty sequence is not defined, this would seem to also be the most logical approach.